# Add UIBarButtomItem as Child of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` embedded in a `UINavigationController`, that starts a `UITabBarController`. The navigation bar is displayed including the back button and I can change the title of the navigation item programmatically from the `UITabBarController`.

But I can't add a `UIBarButtonItem` to the child controllers of the `UITabBarController`. Neither in the storyboard, nor programmatically.

I also tried to embed the child controller in a `UINavigationController`, but that just added a second navigation bar. How do I add `UIBarButtonItem`s from a child of a `UITabBarController`?

[image: My storyboard setup]

Comment: But why you want to add the Bar back button to the TabBar view controller.? Please what your are trying to do so far.

Comment: If adding in storyboard, the navigationItem can be used upto next view controller in stack. Else you've to add your own navigation bar.

Comment: Show your code here...

Comment: No i want to add a button to the right side of the navigation bar, for example on the first child controller of the UITabBarController (the "Info" tab)

Comment: @AmberK Which code? I tried `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtomItem = UIBarButtonItem(...)` and it works in the UITabBarController but not in its child controllers. And i tried to drag a UIBarButtonItem onto the navigation bar in the storyboard

Comment: @PaulMeffle Read my answer and you'll know you not able to do that in child controllers. The navigation bar is one only at beginning of the stack.

Comment: Also in your storyboard I don't see any UITabBarController!!

Comment: @AmberK "PersonDetailController" is a UITabBarController :)

Comment: Oh, that name is a bit misleading. I thought you were using a Master-Detail tableview :)

Comment: Maybe I should :D, i'm new to ios development and it is certainly possible that i am doing things the wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard, your view controller is inside navigation controller. And your child view controller is INSIDE tab bar controller of your view controller. You're not able to add bar button because you're not able to access `navigationController` property (which is nil in your child controller case.)

Debug this by accessing `navigationController` and `tabBarController`. In your case it should be `tabBarController?.navigationController` most probably.

**EDIT**

This is how I maintain navigation bar in code:

```
final class MyVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavigationBar(withTitle: "MyVC")
    }
}
extension UIViewController {
    func setupNavigationBar(withTitle title: String? = nil) {
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: back), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(popVC(animated:)))
        backButton.tintColor = .white
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
        navigationItem.title = title
    }

    @objc
    func popVC(animated: Bool = true) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thanks, i can change the right button from the UITabBarController child using `self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = aButtonItem`

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish the same from the storyboard?

Comment: I don't have experience on that, I guess yes. I prefer to manage all the navigations and routing through code only. But if you want that you can I guess drop another navigation bar from object library. And in `viewDidLoad` hide the parent bar once and wont be shown in subsequent ones.

Comment: Yes that should work, but then i loose the back button that is already there, i think i'll stick to your answer. I'm new to iOS development and i find it confusing how inconvenient it is to do certain things in the storyboard

Comment: There are many drawback of using storyboards, but some plus points too. I'd suggest to use code rather storyboard. If you have some complex UI you can make use nibs. But still that is also doable in code using Stack Views or try some code layout frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code for set the left and right BarButton programatically.You can add the given code in `viewDidload` your child TabBarController.

```
 let cancelBtn =  UIButton(type: .custom)
 cancelBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 15)
 cancelBtn.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
 cancelBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.init(red: 240/255, green: 36/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
 cancelBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cancelBtn)

 let resetBtn =  UIButton(type: .custom)
 resetBtn.setTitle("Reset", for: .normal)
 resetBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.init(red: 240/255, green: 36/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
 resetBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: resetBtn)
```

and also add the following codes to make it sure the property of navigation bar is true..

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    }
```

Comment: I tried it, and it works in the UITabBarController. But not in the child controllers of the UITabBarController and thats where i want to add it

Comment: where did you add the codes ?? in UITabBarController or sub classes

Comment: I added it to `PersonInfoController` which is the first UIViewController of my UITabBarController and it didn't work. But it works if i add it to the UITabBarController itself, but that doesn't achieve what i want to

Comment: That hides the navigation bar, but in combination with embedding the child controller in a navigationController that should work as well. But i prefer @AmberK's answer because it keeps that back button

Answer (score 0):

I have one suggestion for you. Please just remove the `Show Segue` Between the `Person List ViewController` to the `Person Detail ViewController`. and then you **embed In** Navigation to `Person Detail ViewController`.

And on the `didselect` tableview method set the 'Person Detail ViewController` as **RootViewController** Then You can add the NavigationBar Item in the childViewController also.

[image]